# How can you get artifacts 45 and 46?

Tags: just-kill-me

I am in the phase of the game where I need to hunt artifacts to continue the story (I guess?). I was trying for this matter to get all the special artifacts, which are artifacts which will only appear under specific conditions. I am currenctly stuck with the artifacts 45 and 46, which are described with the following pictures: [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEpVd.jpg) and [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVQCO.jpg).

My actual guess is that the gaming space needs to be filled with at least 100 of those items, and then the corresponding artifacts may have a chance to appear. That's what I did for instance with artifact 46, like shown on this picture:

[image]

I filled the gaming space with this specific item, and I'm removing some of these in the pipe on the top so the artifact has some chances to appear. But I don't know if I'm being extremely unlucky or if my idea is wrong, but the artifact never dropped in some days of trying.

Can anyone confirm this theory, or explain what is the real solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theory is correct. In order for each artifact to spawn there must be 100 or more of the specified item in the space.

It can take some time for the artifact to spawn. For me, it could be anywhere from 10-30 minutes. A tip for the "100 or more tama" artifact is to pop multiple tama at once at the bottom of the pipe every 2 seconds or so.

Also, the artifacts look a lot like their corresponding item. The "tama" artifact looks similar to a tama, and the "coin" artifact looks a lot like a coin.